# Changed /etc/fstab Boot freezing in startup, before login. Working in recovery mode

Tags: boot, 17.04, freeze

I'm a recent Ubuntu user. Today I decided to create a swap of my Ubuntu and I followed a tutorial for that. When I complete the tutorial, I insert commands into

```
/etc/fstab
```

and restart the machine. Something went wrong and the machine did not restart. It was frozen before the Login screen.

I entered Grub and entered the recovery mode and decided to comment on the line that carried the Swap in Fstab. When I opened the Nano, I realized that the file was read-only. I did a quick search on the phone for this issue and found a hint for executing the

```
mount / -o remount, rw
```

command. This enabled me to leave Fstab in record mode and then I commented on the line that carried the Swap, recorded the change and left the Grub.

Unfortunately I could not solve the problem. Ubuntu was still freezing. After a few attempts I realized that if I enter the security mode, I go to the terminal and type

```
mount / -o remount, rw
```

, I go back to the options screen and choose "Normal boot resume" then I can enter the security version of Ubuntu and everything works fine except the screen that gets low resolution. But when I reboot the computer, hoping to get into Ubuntu 17.10, it again freezes.

I made a change in the Grub and started to have the startup commands listed on the screen and I realize that when I try to enter Ubuntu 17.10 several lines appear with [Failed], the first is

```
[Failed] Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories. See
'systemctl status systemd-tpfiles-setup.service' for details
```

. The last, before freezing, is:

```
Started stop ureadahead data collection ...
```

Is that all ... any help?

PS.: ALL lines in `/etc/fstab` are commented out.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
# # <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=bdc8b32c-3b83-4d89-a3f6-cacb61e3c19c / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#/swapfile swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your `/etc/fstab` here? I also recommend you add /etc/fstab to the question title. It may also help if you include a link to the tutorial.

Comment: `# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=bdc8b32c-3b83-4d89-a3f6-cacb61e3c19c /  ext4   errors=remount-ro 0    1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#/swapfile   swap    sw      0       0`

Comment: sry, that was a bit confusing. Please include the contents in the original question.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should at least include `/` the root partition into your `/etc/fstab` but maybe your tutorial had a different approach, that i am not aware of.

To fix this quickly, just uncomment your root and swap partition:

```
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=bdc8b32c-3b83-4d89-a3f6-cacb61e3c19c / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
/swapfile swap sw 0 0
```

If something to this setup changed: You can see the list of currently mounted volumes with `cat /etc/mtab`. Try to mount the volumes you need in recovery mode, then list them. After that you can find out the uuids with `sudo blkid` and then insert them into `/etc/fstab`. This is a good idea, if you have some external/changing drives that may end up getting different IDs (sda/sdb...). If you are using some lvm other mappers (e.g. with encryption) then it should look like `/` in my example below.

Here is how my `/etc/fstab` looks like:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# encrypted virtual device
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123412341234 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
# data drive that may get a different id on boot
UUID=1234123412341234 /media/user/Data  ntfs    rw  0 2
```

Comment: Tks @noreabu. I mistakenly commented the line from my root. Uncommented this line solved the problem. Now I followed another tutorial and the swap is working as well.